# How to get HTTP response in a php request

Tags: php

I have a `cron file` that runs to post images to **Instagram**, once the image get posted, the code updates the **MySQL** table as successful. some times, if the logging to Instagram was not successful (or) IP blocked then a server response shows `("status":"fail")`.  how to use (if) to read the http response then update **MySQL** as fail?

PHP Version: 5.6.35

Server http response:

{"message": "checkpoint_required", "checkpoint_url": "https://i.instagram.com/challenge/8633340132/qz34BIU1MQ/", "lock": true, "status": "fail", "error_type": "checkpoint_challenge_required"}

Current posting code:

```
<?php

require_once("helper/functions.php");
require_once("cron_insta_include.php");

$result_outmsg = $database->query("SELECT * FROM insta_sent");
while($row_outmsg = $database->fetch_array($result_outmsg))
{
    if($row_outmsg["report"] == "Scheduled")
    {
        $res_ch = $database->query("SELECT * FROM insta_ch WHERE serial='" . $row_outmsg["fromch"] . "'");
        $row_ch = $database->fetch_array($res_ch);
        if(($row_ch["status"] != "Blocked") && ($row_ch != false))
        {

            if((time() - $row_ch["last_used"]) > 7200)
                {
                try
                    {
                            //Insta Sending
                            $cap = "." . "\r\n\r\n" .  $row_outmsg["body"] . "\r\n\r\n" . "." . "\r\n\r\n" . $row_outmsg["hash"] . "\r\n\r\n" . "." . "\r\n\r\n" . $row_outmsg["tonum"] . "\r\n\r\n" . "." . "\r\n\r\n" . time();
                            $obj = new InstagramUpload();
                            $obj->Login($row_ch["phone"], $row_ch["ch_id"]);
                            $obj->UploadPhoto($row_outmsg["img_lnk"], $cap);

                            sleep(1);
                            $database->query("UPDATE insta_sent SET report='Sent' WHERE serial='" . $row_outmsg["serial"] . "'");
                }

                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                    $database->query("UPDATE insta_sent SET report='Failed' WHERE serial='" . $row_outmsg["serial"] . "'");
                }
                    $sql_13 = "UPDATE insta_ch SET last_used='" . time() . "' WHERE serial='" . $row_outmsg["fromch"] . "'";
                    $database->query($sql_13);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            //$database->query("UPDATE insta_sent SET report='Not Sent' WHERE serial='" . $row_outmsg["serial"] . "'");
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Is this function $obj->UploadPhoto($row_outmsg["img_lnk"], $cap);   return this json string ("status":"fail");

Comment: Hi. If you are using [this lib](https://github.com/LookHin/instagram-photo-video-upload-api) you can't catch any error. Look at [this line](https://github.com/LookHin/instagram-photo-video-upload-api/blob/master/instagram-photo-video-upload-api.class.php#L260) there is only echo, but you need response or exception.

Comment: Actually; if the login to Instagram was not successful, then the reply to the browser is "status":"fail" ... the reply is a text line, and I want to read this reply through my php file then store it in mysql.  Shall I use (var_dump) or (http_response_code) and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP request successfully"; 




else




    echo "
HTTP request not successfully!"; 





?>

Answer (score 0):

You can either use curl directly to get http responses or you can use library like guzzle http. Please refer guzzle http doc : http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Sample curl post request is like this :

```
    $ch = curl_init($api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "your_data_array");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: "length_of_your_data_array"')
    );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj = new InstagramUpload();

$output = $obj->Login($row_ch["phone"], $row_ch["ch_id"]);
$resp = json_decode($output, true);


if($resp['status'] !='fail') {
    $obj->UploadPhoto($row_outmsg["img_lnk"], $cap);
    $database->query("UPDATE insta_sent SET report='Sent' WHERE serial='" . $row_outmsg["serial"] . "'");
}
```

Comment: can you please print the output of login function here in comment.

Comment: this is the output if the post was not successful ... {"message": "checkpoint_required", "checkpoint_url": "https://i.instagram.com/challenge/8633340132/SeKZGX7V5a/", "lock": true, "status": "fail", "error_type": "checkpoint_challenge_required"}

Comment: I'm hoping this is the output of this line. echo $output = $obj->Login($row_ch["phone"], $row_ch["ch_id"]). If yes, then this code works.

Comment: I have edited my question, including the code ... the problem is the not catching the exception

Answer (score 0):

As marv255 pointed out, the used class just prints the result and does not return it. Fortunately, there is also the appropriate PHP function for such scenarios. Just use output buffering.

```
ob_start();
$instance = new InstagramUpload();
$instance->Login($phone, $chid);
$instance->UploadPhoto($image, $caption);
$response = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$result = json_decode($response);
if (!$result) {
    // json string could not be decoded
}

if (property_exists($result, 'status') && $result->status == 'fail') {
    // negative response
} else {
    // positive response
}
```

The `$response` variable now contains the string returned from the API. In this case you can parse the received string and if `fail` occurs, you know that the request has failed and you can save it in your database.

Comment: Did you have a look, what 's inside the `$result` variable? What 's the content? Can you show me the content of $result after you 've dumped it with `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: yes, and this is the output ... 

{"message": "checkpoint_required", "checkpoint_url": "https://i.instagram.com/challenge/8633340132/qz34BIU1MQ/", "lock": true, "status": "fail", "error_type": "checkpoint_challenge_required"}

Comment: Okay ... let us take it a step further. As you can see this is a JSON encoded string. Just make another dump with `var_dump(json_decode($result))`. The expected result should be an object with the properties `message`, `checkoint_url`, `lock`, `status` and `error_type`. The next step should be dumping the `fail` property and look, what 's the value of this property. Programming is sometimes a matter of small steps. The statement "does not work" is not a basis in programming. Sometimes you have to grope step by step to the result and learn.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the cron file to be as follows and still it can not update the MySQL upone failer

```
<?php
require_once("helper/functions.php");
require_once("cron_insta_include.php");

$result_outmsg = $database->query("SELECT * FROM insta_sent");
while($row_outmsg = $database->fetch_array($result_outmsg))
{
    if($row_outmsg["report"] == "Scheduled")
    {
        $res_ch = $database->query("SELECT * FROM insta_ch WHERE serial='" . $row_outmsg["fromch"] . "'");
        $row_ch = $database->fetch_array($res_ch);
        //if(($row_ch["status"] != "Blocked") && ($row_ch != false))

        if($row_ch["status"] == "Active")
        {

            if((time() - $row_ch["last_used"]) > 10800)
                {
                try
                    {
                        //Insta Sending
                        $cap = "." . "\r\n\r\n" .  $row_outmsg["body"] . "\r\n\r\n" . "." . "\r\n\r\n" . $row_outmsg["hash"] . "\r\n\r\n" . "." . "\r\n\r\n" . $row_outmsg["tonum"] . "\r\n\r\n" . "." . "\r\n\r\n" . time();
                        $obj = new InstagramUpload();
                        $obj->Login($row_ch["phone"], $row_ch["ch_id"]);
                        sleep(2);
                        $obj->UploadPhoto($row_outmsg["img_lnk"], $cap);
                        sleep(2);
                        $database->query("UPDATE insta_sent SET report='Sent' WHERE serial='" . $row_outmsg["serial"] . "'");
                    }

                catch(Exception $e)
                    {
                        $database->query("UPDATE insta_sent SET report='Failed' WHERE serial='" . $row_outmsg["serial"] . "'");
                    }

            $sql_13 = "UPDATE insta_ch SET last_used='" . time() . "' WHERE serial='" . $row_outmsg["fromch"] . "'";
            $database->query($sql_13);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            $database->query("UPDATE insta_sent SET report='Not Sent' WHERE serial='" . $row_outmsg["serial"] . "'");
        }
    }
}

?>
```